# Set options to option dialog Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have get a JSON string from server:

```
genre [
 'type1',
 'type2',
 'type3',
 'type4'
```

]

I want to get values in array genre to add to option in option_dialog.I declared:

```
var genreArr=[];
for(var i=0;i<genre.length;i++) 
{
 genreArr.push(genre[i]));
}
```

Then I create option dialog and set options for it.

```
var option_dialog=Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({});
option_dialog.options=genreArr;
```

But when click option dialog it dont' display values in array genreArr.Can you help me.Thank

Comment: Where is your event handler ? which executes
`option_dialog.show()`
and what is your target device?

and it seems there is an extra ')' at
`genreArr.push(genre[i]));`

Answer (score 2):

`options` is a CREATION-ONLY property, as specified in [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.OptionDialog-property-options). You must pass it to your createOptionDialog call, as demonstrated below.

```
var genre = [
    'type1',
    'type2',
    'type3',
    'type4'
];

var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
    options: genre,
    title: 'Pick a Genre'
});
dialog.addEventListener('click', function(evt)
{
    alert('You picked ' + genre[evt.index]);
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Could you try to explain to me why this code work for me on iOS ? :

`var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({})
 win.open()
 
 var showopt = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title:"Show Options"
 })
 showopt.addEventListener("click",function() {
  opt.show();
 })
 win.add(showopt)
 optarr = ["Test","Test1","Test2"]
 var opt = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
  //options:optarr
 })
 opt.options = optarr`
Thanks =)

Comment: Divergence from the specifications.

Comment: Might want to hit the check mark, if it answered your question.

Comment: Thanks =)
ok, so it just might work for some and for some not, but you should use it as an creational option?

Comment: Yes, use it as a creation argument. That'll work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way which i have use in my code

```
   var genre = [
    'type1',
    'type2',
    'type3',
    'type4'
];
```

// call the option dialog in onclick listener

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog(genre).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"Prompting the Device to Vibrate",
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"
});

var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Your choice will appear here",
    width:"auto",
    height:"auto"
});

//The option dialog is very similar to the alert dialog in its creation and handling
var colorDialog = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog({
    title:"What color do you like?",
    options: ["Yellow","Surprise me","No thanks"],
    cancel:2//The index in the options array that defines which of the buttons is a cancel button
});

var optionButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"Option Dialog!",
    height:48,
    width:120,
    bottom:12
});

colorDialog.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.index < 2){
        if(e.index === 0){
            win.backgroundColor = "#FFCC00";
        }else if(e.index === 1){
            win.backgroundColor = "#329FF0";
        }

    //Access the button index via e.index
    //Use that index with e.source.buttonNames to return th button name tapped: e.source.buttonNames[e.index]
    label.text = "You tapped index " + e.index;

    }else{
        label.text = "Aww shucks...";
    }

});

optionButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    colorDialog.show();
});


win.add(label);
win.add(optionButton);
win.open();
```